# jQuery DatePicker and JQuery Modal Popups Issue in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a situation where I have a form with:

- a view
- popup1 (with popup1.js)
- popup2 (with popup2.js)
- I have set the input boxes to have a class of either popup1Date or popup2Date in case the
  issue   was coming from having them all set to the same date class.

The isuse occurs if I go into popup1 - close - then into popup2 - select a date, it won't set the date in the input box.

If I only ever go into one popup, it works fine.

Also, I tried putting an alert in popup1's onSelect and it seems to fire on popup2's onselect, even though they are in different .js files.

There is a lot of code to post so I'm hoping someone has came accross a similar issue or has any advice or pointers.

Here is the date code at least:

```
//EDIT
$('#BaseReconEdit').live('click', function(e) {
    var url = '/PaymentVariable/EditBaseRecon/' + $(this).attr('rowsid');
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#VarBaseRecon_InputDiv').html(data);


        //date code
        $('.popUp1Date).datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            onSelect: function(date) { alert(date) },
            buttonImage: '/Content/images/Control_MonthCalendar.bmp',
            buttonText: 'Enter Date',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            yearRange: '-20:+20',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });

    $('#VarBaseRecon_InputDiv').dialog('option', 'title', 'Edit Base Recon');
    $("#VarBaseRecon_InputDiv").dialog('open');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As tyou can see, I click a button, load the partial and set up it's own datePicker.  This code is similar but with unique class ids in the other .js file.

Any help at all appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I get it working is to assign id as the selector instead of class.  That way, there is no confusion.